# AOSP: where to store factory data?

Tags: android, android-source, production, ota, serial-number

I am working on a custom device for which I customized the Android port of a TechNexion i.MX8 SOM.

During production, our factory requires that production data (order number, serial number, and other production related information for traceability) be stored into the device.

I can store all of this in a file but my concern is that this production data may be lost after an OTA update.

Is there a mechanism in place to store permanent data (such as production data) to make sure that this will never be erased?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Talk with your device vendor, this is usually a part handled by them. Each vendor implementation is a bit different, but usually all of them have an extra "device-info" partition in which those data are persisted, this way they survive OTA and manual flash

Comment: Very interesting, thanks for the tip. I'll check with my vendor then.